# Expecting right curly bracket, found 'else'

Tags: apex, class, compile-error

I am using if else loop in my method, facing this error while compilation.

> Expecting right curly bracket, found 'else'

Here is my method:

```
public List<SelectOption> actionTypeOptions {
    get {
      if (actionTypeOptions == null) {
        actionTypeOptions = new List<SelectOption>{new SelectOption('', '--None--')};
        }

        if(division == 'val1' && subDivision == 'val2'){
        for (Action_Type_Options__c a : Action_Type_Options__c.getall().values()) {
          actionTypeOptions.add(new SelectOption(a.Value__c, a.Name));
        }
        else{
        for (Action_Type_Options__c a : Action_Type_Options__c.getall().values()) {
          actionTypeOptions.add(new SelectOption(a.Value1__c, a.Name));

            }
            }

      }
      actionTypeOptions.sort();

      return actionTypeOptions;
    } 
    set;
  }
```

Comment: This issue can be avoided by using indentation consistently.  I suggest adopting a style guide such as [Google's Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(division == 'Honda' && subDivision == 'Campaign'){
        for (Action_Type_Options__c a : Action_Type_Options__c.getall().values()) {
          actionTypeOptions.add(new SelectOption(a.Value__c, a.Name));
        }
}
```

You're missing to close one bracket here. Before the else.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing bracket after your loop inside the `if` statement.

You need:

```
if (condition)
{
    for (...)
    {
        ...
    }
} // MISSING
else
{
    for (...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```